# Zod equivalent of Yup's schemaOf

Tags: zod

In Yup, you can have code like this:

```js
import * as yup from "yup";

interface Dog {
  name: string;
}

const DogSchema: yup.SchemaOf<Dog> = yup.object({
  name: yup.string()
});
```

Here, `yup.SchemaOf` enforces that `DogSchema` and `Dog` are in agreement.

Any way to do that in Zod?

(I'm aware that, in most cases, using `yup.InferType` or `z.infer` is a more concise way to do this)

Comment: Two relevant GitHub issues: [#372](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/372) and [#53](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/53).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I'm not sure this is correct... according to [here](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/2559#discussioncomment-6383156), it's not officially supported.

Found it: `z.ZodType`.

The example becomes:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

interface Dog {
  name: string;
}

const DogSchema: z.ZodType<Dog> = z.object({
  name: z.string()
});
```